# int main (int argc, char *argv[]) не принимает русские символы в качестве аргумента

Tags: c, main, argv

Может где-то есть ответ, но я не успел найти а может мало искал...

Почему int main (int argc, char *argv[]) не принимает русские символы в качестве аргумента...
Точнее он их принимает, но воспринимает как то иначе...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char line[80];
    if (argc != 6)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, ("Вы должны передать 5 элементов\n"));
        return (1);
    }
    FILE *in;
    if (!(in = fopen("spoky.csv", "r")))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Не удалось открыть spoky.csv");
        return (2);
    }
    FILE *file1 = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    FILE *file2 = fopen(argv[4], "w");
    FILE *file3 = fopen(argv[5], "w");

    while (fscanf(in, "%79[^\n]\n", line) == 1)
    {
        if (strstr(line, argv[1]))
            fprintf(file1, "%s\n", line);

        else if (strstr(line, argv[3]))
            fprintf(file2, "%s\n", line);

        else
            fprintf(file3, "%s\n", line);
    }
    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
    fclose(file3);
    return (0);
}
```

Вот команда для запуска программы: spoky.exe elvis elvis.csv нло ufo.csv other.csv

Причем английскую строку он хорошо выводит в отдельный файл (elvis -> elvis.csv) А русские строки как то иначе воспринимает....

Си только начал изучать... Не тороплюсь, Желаю вникнуть во все!
Помогите, подскажите кто знает почему это так и как решить возможно?

Comment: Если компилятор от Microsoft, то вам подойдет [`wmain`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-language/using-wmain?view=vs-2019)

Comment: `int main() {    SetConsoleOutputCP( CP_UTF8 );}` или `int main() {
    SetConsoleOutputCP( CP_1251 );`

Comment: Не работает (((

Comment: Насколько я точно знаю это работает на C++ но не на C

Comment: Нужно в консоле режим поставить: >`chcp 1251`. И в исходнике си ту же кодировку использовать. Если у вас в проге другая, то её.

Comment: Все именно так и делал... 
Ничего не выходит... Использую vscode бяка всякая... А так хочется использовать Великий и Могучий русский язык....

Comment: Я даже библиотеку подключил #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

Comment: Сейчас кстати пробовал этот же код на Linux запустить, так там тоже проблема, русские символы автоматически перекодировались в ироглифы... Что за напасть?

Comment: Понятно, что дело в разных кодировках, которые используются виндой при передаче аргументов командной строки, ввода с клавиатуры и хранимых в файле символов. Для начала просто распечатайте коды символов ваших строк, чтобы можно было разобраться что и как настраивать. Обычно ввод с клавиатуры происходит в CP-866, а аргументы преобразуются в CP-1251.

Comment: так какой компилятор то... тут вещи сильно зависящие от реализации. Это уже не в язык упор а в осрбенности платформы. Если с майкрософтским, майкрософт не поддерживает Си, их разработчик черным по белому писал ) так что все одинаково для обоих.

Comment: Запустил под линуксом, предварительно записав в spoky.csv строку "нло".  В результате в файле ufo.csv оказалась строка "нло". Локаль — ru_RU.UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, потому что на вашей платформе кириллица - не восьмибитная кодировка , а UTF-8 юникод или расширенный символ (wchar_t). То есть, каждая буква представлена более чем одним байтом. А в случае с линукс, может быть и то и другое и это надо обрабатывать., способ обработки\преобразования зависит от платформы, если вы не пользуетесь какими-то  кроссплатформенными библиотеками.

По коду видно, что это Windows, в  MSDN есть статья о том как пребразовывать строки.   Программу надо компилировать с поддерждкой unicode. Тут еще все осложнится тем что имена файлов в системе уже UTF-16 а не UTF-8..

Comment: Да это Windows10

Comment: на Linux у меня такой проблемы не было вроде, но я попробую. И вот проблема кроется сейчас именно в argv[] те что принимаю из командной строки, он их действительно воспринимает не так.. Что-то похожее на то что вы сказали UTF-16 а не UTF-8 

А как можно изменить то это? ))

Comment: При том что когда считываю просто файл не через argv[...] Все отлично работает и русские символы и английские отображаются